# How to change the text in QPushbutton within a QButtongroup element after some user input?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm currently switching from using Tk in my Python scripts to PyQt to run some simple GUIs. They are intended to provide features that will be saved later in a file together with some data which will be collected after a different script is started (separate PushButton which I left out for the time being). Right now, I cannot get my head around how to change the text of some Pushbottons depending on the user's input. To be more precise I would like to display the same buttons but either with BTNS = ["1", "2", ... "8"] or BTNS = ["9", "10", ... "16"], depending upon the input of a different Pushbutton ("Right" vs. "Left"). I have tried different approaches (fetching information from findChildren within the group, using deleteLater, using the clicked argument and so on) but nothing gives the result I am looking for.

Here is a MWE of my problem.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 500)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.MainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.lbl1 = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl1.setText('Test1:')
        self.lbl1.move(50, 80)
        self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.lbl1)

        self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.addSideButtons())

        self.btnGroup2 = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.MainLayout.addWidget(self.StimButtons("left"))

        self.show()

    def addSideButtons(self):

        self.btnGroup1 = QButtonGroup()
        self.button1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton(self)

        self.button1.setGeometry(90, 20, 100, 30)
        self.button1.setText("Left")
        self.button1.setCheckable(True)
        #self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.StimButtons("left"))
        self.button1.setChecked(True)
        self.btnGroup1.addButton(self.button1)

        self.button2.setGeometry(200, 20, 100, 30)
        self.button2.setText("Right")
        self.button2.setCheckable(True)
        #self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.StimButtons("right"))
        self.btnGroup1.addButton(self.button2)
        self.btnGroup1.setExclusive(True)

    def StimButtons(self, btn):

        if btn == "left":
            BTNS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
        else:
            BTNS = ["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"]

        coords = [(150, 350), (80, 300), (150, 300), (220, 300),
                    (80, 250), (150, 250), (220, 250), (150, 200)]

        for idx, contact_bts in enumerate(BTNS):
            self.btn = QPushButton(contact_bts, self)
            self.btn.setGeometry(coords[idx][0], coords[idx][1], 60, 45)
            self.btn.setCheckable(True)
            self.btnGroup2.addButton(self.btn)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reuse the buttons instead of deleting them and creating them so you first create the buttons in a method that will only be called once. In another method you must change the text of the buttons depending on the button pressed, and for this you must send a feature that identifies the button, in this case the button pressed will be sent using the buttonClicked signal of the QButtonGroup. On the other hand as a plus I have restructured your code to use layout.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 600, 500)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.m_buttons = []

        group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        left_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Left", checkable=True)
        right_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Right", checkable=True)
        group.addButton(left_button)
        group.addButton(right_button)
        group.buttonClicked[QtWidgets.QAbstractButton].connect(self.update_text)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Test1:")

        self.m_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.create_buttons()

        left_button.click()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addStretch()
        hlay.addWidget(left_button)
        hlay.addWidget(right_button)
        hlay.addStretch()
        lay.addLayout(hlay)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(self.m_widget, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addStretch()

    def create_buttons(self):
        coords = [
            (4, 1),
            (3, 0),
            (3, 1),
            (3, 2),
            (2, 0),
            (2, 1),
            (2, 2),
            (0, 1),
        ]
        group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(exclusive=True)
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.m_widget)
        for coord in coords:
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(checkable=True)
            btn.setFixedSize(60, 45)
            grid.addWidget(btn, *coord)
            group.addButton(btn)
            self.m_buttons.append(btn)
        self.m_widget.setFixedSize(self.m_widget.sizeHint())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton)
    def update_text(self, btn):
        text = btn.text()
        texts = {
            "Left": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
            "Right": ["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"],
        }
        if text in texts:
            for btn, txt in zip(self.m_buttons, texts[text]):
                btn.setText(txt)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = App()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]